# How can I hide overflown text as ellipsis using dynamic bootstrap cols

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to align a text next to an icon inside a card. The card is wrapped inside the Bootstrap "col" class which dynamically determines its size depending on how many items a row contains.

However if there isn't enough space the text gets wrapped and is displayed in a second row. Now what I'm trying to achieve is to keep the text next to the icon on one line and end it if there isn't enough space with an ellipsis (three dots).

[This plunker shows my current setup](https://plnkr.co/edit/BV9PUOhTVgfoNRNv9xkg)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="row mx-1">
      <div class="col" style="background:lightgray">
        <div class="row">
          <div style="width:50px;height:50px;background:gray"></div>
          <div>
            <div class="title">
              Normal title
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="col mx-1" style="background:lightgray">
        <div class="row">
          <div style="width:50px;height:50px;background:gray"></div>
          <div>
            <div class="title">
              Long title which should end with ellipsis
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="col mx-1" style="background:lightgray">
        <div class="row">
          <div style="width:50px;height:50px;background:gray"></div>
          <div>
            <div class="title">
              Long title which should end with ellipsis
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="col mx-1" style="background:lightgray">
        <div class="row">
          <div style="width:50px;height:50px;background:gray"></div>
          <div>
            <div class="title">
              Long title which should end with ellipsis
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="col mx-1" style="background:lightgray">
        <div class="row">
          <div style="width:50px;height:50px;background:gray"></div>
          <div>
            <div class="title">
              Long title which should end with ellipsis
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

[What I'm trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsaqR.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An idea is to make your text out of the flow using absolute position and then add some CSS properties to crop the text:

```css
.main-title {
  flex: 1;
  position: relative;
}

.main-title .title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row mx-1">
    <div class="col" style="background:lightgray">
      <div class="row">
        <div style="width:50px;height:50px;background:gray"></div>
        <div class="main-title">
          <div class="title">
            Normal title
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="col mx-1" style="background:lightgray">
      <div class="row">
        <div style="width:50px;height:50px;background:gray"></div>
        <div class="main-title">
          <div class="title">
            Long title which should end with ellipsis
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="col mx-1" style="background:lightgray">
      <div class="row">
        <div style="width:50px;height:50px;background:gray"></div>
        <div class="main-title">
          <div class="title">
            Long title which should end with ellipsis
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="col mx-1" style="background:lightgray">
      <div class="row">
        <div style="width:50px;height:50px;background:gray"></div>
        <div class="main-title">
          <div class="title">
            Long title which should end with ellipsis
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="col mx-1" style="background:lightgray">
      <div class="row d-flex">
        <div style="width:50px;height:50px;background:gray"></div>
        <div class="main-title">
          <div class="title">
            Long title which should end with ellipsis
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ultimately, your answer was accepted and I do think it's a very good answer because it doesn't require changing HTML. (although changing HTML can sometimes be a good idea) So, I'm gonna give you a 10-point bump also (although I don't think you'd care about a tiny 10-point bump at your current level). :-)

Comment: @WebDevBooster well i think he accepted my answer because of no HTML changes and maybe because i was the first ... by the way the accepted mark has no big meaning, as you may notice in some well known questions that the accepted answer is not always the best ;) the important thing is that each one gave a different approach and both can be usefull to not only the OP and i personaly like yours because i always think that making content out of the flow should be done at a last requirement

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `text-truncate` class to automatically truncate (and add ellipsis) based on the available space in a column.

To achieve that you need to put your content into columns (which you should always do anyway because putting stuff directly into a row tends to lead to problems that require unnecessary css hacks).

In the following snippet, you see a much cleaner version of your code that achieves the desired result using the `text-truncate` class:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
<style>
.grey-div {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background:gray;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
</style>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row mx-1">
        <div class="col px-0 mx-1" style="background:lightgray">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="grey-div"></div>
                <div>
                    <div class="title">
                        Normal title
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col px-0 mx-1 text-truncate" style="background:lightgray">
            <div class="title text-truncate">
                <div class="grey-div"></div>
                Long title which should end with ellipsis
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col px-0 mx-1 text-truncate" style="background:lightgray">
            <div class="title text-truncate">
                <div class="grey-div"></div>
                Long title which should end with ellipsis
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col px-0 mx-1 text-truncate" style="background:lightgray">
            <div class="title text-truncate">
                <div class="grey-div"></div>
                Long title which should end with ellipsis
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col px-0 mx-1 text-truncate" style="background:lightgray">
            <div class="title text-truncate">
                <div class="grey-div"></div>
                Long title which should end with ellipsis
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can also use the `text-truncate` class to truncate automatically, based on the available width of the column. But you'd have to restructure your code for that a little.

Comment: but this solution need a fixed width and i guess it's not the intention, by the way why not adding your other way you commented

Comment: @TemaniAfif Well, he has fixed width in the code already. So, I was assuming that fixed width is desired in this case. To truncate automatically, the code has to be changed significantly.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Really? And what's this: `style="width:50px;height:50px;background:gray"`

Comment: check well the code ;) this is for the icon that will stay next to the text. It has nothing to do with the text. And you added a the fixed width 100px

Comment: **Bootstrap "col" class which dynamically determines its size depending on how many items a row contains** and **I'm trying to achieve is to keep the text next to the icon on one line**

Comment: @TemaniAfif Just updated my code snippet. While betting against you would usually be a lost case, that is definitely NOT today! Today, I present a super clean version that works with a Bootstrap class and does the job just as well!  :-)

Comment: yes i agree ;) it's good and clean so +1 :) ... by the way the use of row here without col can be accepted because it's nested and the negative margin are handled by col padding, but i agree it's better to put in col. By the way don't forget to also apply your logic to the first title to make all the code coherent ;)